# How can I see what keyboard shortcut a key is bound to in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, keyboard, command, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to type a question mark into the tooptip text box of a control in the properties panel, and suddenly I got switched into code view. It turns out <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (or <kbd>?</kbd>) now seems to be bound to a command I've never heard of which navigates to the next event handler that's referenced in XAML. So now I can't type question marks since the shortcut seems to be global.

I'd like to be able to figure out how to change this behavior, but the search bar in the keyboard options only seems to search for commands and not for shortcuts. How do I find what command is being triggered and why?

Comment: Think [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx) should of help!

Comment: Thanks! I searched it. No ? or shift+/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the keyboard options dialog, press a shortcut in the **Press shortcut keys** box. **Shortcut currently used by** list will show all currently assigned commands for this shortcut:

[image]