# In Visual Code editor, how can I which functions a key is bound to?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code *editor* (not Visual Studio to which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035286/waiting-for-second-key-of-chord) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054927/how-can-i-see-what-keyboard-shortcut-a-key-is-bound-to-in-visual-studio) applies) how can I know which function is bound to a particular keyboard shortcut?

I know about assigning a keyboard shortcut to a function and then using the conflict resolution option that the editor provides to resolve any overloaded keystrokes.  What I want to know is how to find which function is assigned to a particular keystroke.  Apparently, in Visual Studio (IDE) there's an option to use a "Shortcut currently used by" dialog so that you could type in a keystroke/chord and it would show the function (rather than execute it) (see links above).  Emacs has the same type of thing where you can type a keystroke and see what it is bound to.

The backstory on this: I used to open the recent files list via `ctrl+R`.  Recently it says "Waiting for second key of chord...".  I can see that the recent files function is STILL bound to `ctrl+R` but short of eyeball browsing hundreds of commands I can't determine how to backtrack to find whatever is using the `ctrl+R` key chord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your keyboard shortcuts preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>). The search input field has a keyboard icon on the right side. Click that - or press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> - to record keys and VS Code will show you all commands for that specific keybinding.

Comment: Bingo... that's what I needed.  Now that I have it, though, I realize it doesn't show you all the possible "key chord" completions.  So if I hit "ctrl-r" it only shows me what the basic cntrl-r does.  Maybe I need to ask for an enhancement there.  Thanks for your reponse, that's helpful!